# Can a dedicated IP for SSL be bought from anywhere?

Tags: ssl-certificate

Can a dedicated IP be bought from anywhere, or do you have to buy it from the company that hosts the site?
I ask this because if I could buy it from elsewhere, I'm sure that I'll be able to find a better deal than what is being currently offered.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not who you buy it from, the problem is how packets get routed to the machine. Most hosting companies have their routers set up so that only addresses they provide can get to the machines they own/colocate, therefore you must purchase additional IP addresses from them.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi, Can a dedicated IP be bought from
>   anywhere, or do you have to buy it
>   from the company that hosts the site

Well, first of all, you can not BUY an IP Address. They are if anything leased. Second, not as addresses, but as address ranges, preferred with 4906 addreses minimum for international routing.

I suggest talking to your provider.